# Classes getting Unloaded during Full GC ( and before OOM )?

Tags: java

I understand that classes once loaded by a ClassLoader will never get unloaded.

But look at teh following output from a Weblogic JVM before it went out of memory.

Does this mean that JVM tried to unload a bunch of classes in a desperate attempt to reclaim memory ? ( Maybe weak reference ? )

--sony

```
111812.602: [Full GC[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1390]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4153]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4155]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5253]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5251]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7012]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5231]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5252]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4149]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5270]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5269]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7011]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor348]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4152]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7143]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1680]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1684]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5650]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5232]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5254]
…
…
…
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4540]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4537]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4085]
[Unloading class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor411]
[PSYoungGen: 466089K->0K(1201792K)] [ParOldGen: 3112457K->3186267K(3413376K)] 3578546K->3186267K(4615168K) [PSPermGen: 599209K->587324K(786432K)], 5.9899030 secs] [Times: user=21.70 sys=0.00, real=5.99 secs]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[Loaded sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor352 from __JVM_DefineClass__]
[Loaded sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor353 from __JVM_DefineClass__]
Dumping heap to /opt/app/p1ibp3m2/appl/ordermanagement/log/java_pid24100.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [4016788478 bytes in 82.703 secs]
[Loaded sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor354 from __JVM_DefineClass__]
***************************************************************************
The WebLogic Server encountered a critical failure
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7) gives reasons why a class should not be unloaded if it's classloader is still reachable. However, these reasons do not apply to these internal classes generated by JVM, therefore it's safe to unload them.

Comment: The question is whether unloading these classes can affect our application semantics. That seems unlikely. Maybe we could try `forName()` and observe that the behavior violates JLS; however `forName()` can be implemented not to return these classes - in that case, they are not "normal" classes that concern a java program.

Comment: I came across XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled. It indeed looks like classes can be unloaded. But then if JLS specifies the class unloading behavior, then this switch should be in violation f JLS ?